GMB Quota metric Requests and limit Requests per minute
Hi i need help how do i get quota Requests per minute?.
Im trying to connect google my business profile to an app that will do a post schedule service th eapp is in development mode but i was never able to connect a google  my business profile.
The app is a saas but i dont sell anything its for personal use only.
so every time im trying to connect a google my business profile i get the following message
Quota exceeded for quota metric 'Requests' and limit 'Requests per minute' of service 'mybusinessaccountmanagement.googleapis.com' for consumer 'project_number:------'.**
image Under My Business Business Information API 
Under the Tab Quotas & System Limits
i send a request to google to increase the Requests per minute quota and they added everyhting else i dont need. The picture below shows that the request per min is 0 and then i email back asking a question about the per min and i got en email say ...
"Dear Developer,
For support related questions, please reach out to the Google Cloud Platform community support at https://cloud.google.com/support/#community."
i research and i found someone was talking about it on this link but not sure how to fix this or who to talk to :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66785834/quota-exceeded-for-quota-metric-requests-and-limit-requests-per-minute-of-se
What i should do?
